# Android 4.4 translucent status and navigation in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I rarely use android so I was quite surprised to find out android had translucent status/hardware-navigation bars.

Is this a feature that is possible to toggle in cordova? 
There is [this article](http://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/) about doing it in native code, xml, but you have to go dive into the android apps structure.

Is this a setting you could toggle in the `config.xml`?